# Cordova3.5 形式に移行してトラブル発生

Tags: monaca, cordova

**MonacaにてCordova2.9 形式からCordova3.5 形式へ移行しビルドしたところ、アンドロイド端末において**

３点ほど問題が発生しました。対処方法をお分かりになる方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。

**・ステータス（ツール）バー消えてしまいました。

・アンドロイド端末からアイコンが消えてしまった。

・スプラッシュスクリーンが表示されなくなった。**

デバッガーは、ＨＴＭＬ部分のみ表示されますが、以前から、ステータス（ツール）バー
は表示されませんでしたが、インストールしたアンドロイド端末では、表示されていました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ３件の不具合について、どのようなコードの箇所で発生している記述していただけると、回答しやすいです。また、現在3件の不具合を１つの質問にまとめてしまっていますが、3つの質問に分割した方が、回答を得られやすいと思いますよ。

Answer (score 3):

MonacaにてCordova2.9 形式からCordova3.5 形式へ移行後は
色々と管理画面から設定し直しが必要です
コードの書き換えも必要な箇所があります
ご質問の解決策も見つかるかと思われます
私もかなり苦戦しました

まずは下記のガイドを読まれるとよいかと思います
https://642dad3ff5abc36218998a19ee31a174f322b763.googledrive.com/host/0B-F5PfgMvTC9dmJONEtWY2xCRm8/201412/conversion_from2_9.html

さらに最近Cordova4.1 になりましたのでこちらもお読みいただくとよいと思います

http://blog.asial.co.jp/1356